# collectionView cell not working in tapGestureRecognizer function

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to change a cell label text when I click/tap on a collectionView cell.
I tried the following way, but this not working.

```
@objc func tap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let location = sender.location(in: self.collectionView)
        let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: location)
        if let index = indexPath {

            let subL = zoneDict?.sublevel[index.row]

            if (subL?.sublevel.count)! > 0 {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.zoneDict = subL!
                    print("self.zoneDict --\(self.zoneDict!)")
                    let cell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "colViewCell", for: index) as! CollectionViewCell

                    cell.zoneNameLabel.text = self.zoneDict?.name // Cannot update the text label. It show the default value
                    print("zone name-- \(self.zoneDict?.name)") // Its print the result.
                }
                self.delegate?.selectedZoneWithCellItems(items: "cell")
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply do it in didSelectItemAt

Comment: I tried it didSelectItemAt also. Another thing is this collectionView is a subView of a tableView. If the tapped sublevel have values, then it pass a signal to tableView, and tableView will add a row which contains the collectionViewcell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you tap `collectionViewCell` then iOS system default call function `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` of `CollectionView` so that you must handle default event selected cell by the way register `UITapGestureRecognizer` for your cell and after that you must set property of view (`isUserInteractionEnabled = true`).
For example: `self.yourview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Answer (score 0):

you can use this in the VC containing the collection view

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = segmentCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: SegmentCellId, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(printHello))
        cell.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        return cell
    }

@objc func printHello(){
        print("Hello")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use its delegate method in this way to change the cell label text when clicked on cell: -> Here I am using two arrays to update the text of the label as an example: 
//Variables that are used below.

let nameCapitalArr1 = ["ABC", "DFG", "EFG", "HIJ", "KLM", "NOP", "QRS", "TUV", "WXY", "Z"]

let nameSmallArr2 = ["abc", "dfg", "efg", "hij", "klm", "nop", "qrs", "tuv", "wxy", "z"]

var changeFlag: Bool = false

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nameCapitalArr1.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    guard let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "LabelTextCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as? LabelTextCollectionViewCell else { return UICollectionViewCell() }

    cell.nameTextLabel.text = !changeFlag ?  nameCapitalArr1[indexPath.row] : nameSmallArr2[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

/*That method is called when tapping on the cell and reload that particular cell and also change the label text.*/

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    changeFlag = !changeFlag
    collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}
```

Output: -> Its reflect the cell text with capital to small array values while tapping on the cell with toggle effect.